# Get AWS CloudWatch Live Metrics for nagios monitoring

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to fetch live AWS Cloudwatch metrics for CPU, memory utilization using AWS CLI.

I was able to get the metrics between the time period using this command

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name CPUUtilization --start-time 2023-08-17 --end-time 2023-08-18 --namespac
e AWS/ElastiCache --period 3600 --statistics Average
```

but I am looking for a enhanced way to get the live metrics and use those metrics for nagios monitoring, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the *get-metric-statistics* command for aws cloudwatch CLI command

```
time_now=`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`
time_past_5_min=`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S -d "now -5 minutes"`

utilization_type=CPUUtilization #DatabaseMemoryUsagePercentage
cluster_id=uat-db-node

aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name "${utilization_type}" --start-time "${time_past_5_min}" --end-time "${time_now}" \
 --namespace AWS/ElastiCache --period 60 --statistics Average --dimensions Name=CacheClusterId,Value="${cluster_id}"
```